# Building dataframe given scalar and json tabular data?

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider I have and id:

```
id <- 1
```

and a JSON file with columns (here converted the result of `fromJSON`):

```
fromJSON(j$sensorsData)
                [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]          [,8]          [,9]         [,10]
   [1,] 6.924485e+14 3.2289276 5.886124 7.571915 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.0000000000 -1.0000000000 -1.0000000000
   [2,] 6.924485e+14 3.2313232 6.016602 7.492905 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.0000000000 -1.0000000000 -1.0000000000
   [3,] 6.924485e+14 3.1798400 6.029770 7.270248 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.0000000000 -1.0000000000 -1.0000000000
   [4,] 6.924485e+14 3.1882324 6.001038 7.260666 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.0000000000 -1.0000000000 -1.0000000000
```

Now I want to create a dataframe with first column id and "bind_cols" of my above matrix + give names to columns for example "col1" through "col10".

I am trying to do this with

```
set_names(data_frame(uuid, as_data_frame(fromJSON(j$sensorsData))), 
                            nm = c("id", "timestamp", 
                                   "acc_x", "acc_y", "acc_z", 
                                   "grav_x", "grav_y", "grav_z", 
                                   "gyro_x", "gyro_y", "gyro_z"))
```

but it doesn't give me the desired result:

```
id col1          col2       .... to col10
1  6.924485e+14  3.2289276          -1.0000000000
1  6.924485e+14  3.2313232          -1.0000000000  
1  6.924485e+14  3.1798400          -1.0000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `tibble` package just replace `data_frame` with `add_column`:

```
set_names(add_column(uuid=id, as_data_frame(fromJSON(j$sensorsData))), 
                        nm = c("id", "timestamp", 
                               "acc_x", "acc_y", "acc_z", 
                               "grav_x", "grav_y", "grav_z", 
                               "gyro_x", "gyro_y", "gyro_z"))
```

If you use `dplyr` package:

```
set_names(dplyr::bind_cols(uuid=rep(id,nrow(as_data_frame(fromJSON(j$sensorsData)))), as_data_frame(fromJSON(j$sensorsData))), 
      nm = c("id", "timestamp", 
             "acc_x", "acc_y", "acc_z", 
             "grav_x", "grav_y", "grav_z", 
             "gyro_x", "gyro_y", "gyro_z"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very nice, liked the `add_column`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
names <- c("id", "timestamp", 
  "acc_x", "acc_y", "acc_z", 
  "grav_x", "grav_y", "grav_z", 
  "gyro_x", "gyro_y", "gyro_z")

df <- cbind(id=1, fromJSON(j$sensorsData)); colnames(df) <- names
```

Comment: This is not my question, I want to bind a dataframe and a scalar.

Comment: @steves Oh right. That can be done like so `cbind(id = 1, df)`

Comment: I just thought I can do this in one liner... I like short and efficient solutions

Comment: @steves the solution above will bind the scalar to your dataframe and assign the names all in one line